# I am not able show another controller using presentModalViewController:

Tags: iphone

Please see the code

```
   -(IBAction)startGame{
NSLog(@"Button is pressed");

CharadesAppDelegate  *del=(CharadesAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
[del setAllTeams:teamDict];
[del setScore:selectedScroll];
Playing *p=[[Playing alloc]init];
    [self presentModalViewController:p animated:YES];

}
```

I want to present Playing controller which only contains following line

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"]];
```

}
but unfortunately I am not able to switch to another controller nothing happens when I press the button , please help

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a nib file for the `Playing` UIViewController, you should use a different `-init`:

```
Playing *playingVC = [[Playing alloc] initWithNibName:@"Playing" bundle:nil];
```

Remember to change the nib name.